# InterLockedIncrement does not support second parameter?

Tags: delphi

I want to do

```
InterLockedIncrement(counter, step)
```

but the compiler says

too many parameters

Is there an API for taking a second parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows function you are looking for is named [`InterlockedAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683504.aspx). But I don't believe that Delphi's RTL offers this function, probably because it is actually implemented as a compiler intrinsic by the MS tool chain.

There is also [`TInterlocked.Add`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Add) which would serve your needs.

But I think that the best bet is the intrinsic function [`AtomicIncrement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AtomicIncrement). Call it like this:

```
AtomicIncrement(SomeVar, SomeAddend);
```

The advantages of the intrinsic are:

1. It is cross-platform.
2. It is inlined and so avoids the cost of a function call.

Comment: Note that `TInterlocked` is available only in XE+, and `AtomicIncrement()` is available only in XE3+.

Comment: For earlier than XE3 I would just write my own asm version of AtomicIncrement using asm.

Answer (score 7):

[`InterlockedIncrement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614.aspx) only has one parameter - the variable to increment by 1:

```
function InterlockedIncrement(var Addend: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

> Increments (increases by one) the value of the specified 32-bit variable as an atomic operation.
>
> Parameters
>
> Addend [in, out]
>   A pointer to the variable to be incremented.

For what you are asking, there is an [`InterlockedAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683504.aspx) function, but it is not available in Delphi.  You can use the [`InterlockedExchangeAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683597.aspx) function instead:

```
function InterlockedExchangeAdd(var Addend: Integer; Value: Integer): Integer stdcall;
```

> Performs an atomic addition of two 32-bit values.
>
> Parameters
>
> Addend [in, out]
>   A pointer to a variable. The value of this variable will be replaced with the result of the operation.
>
> Value [in]
>   The value to be added to the variable pointed to by the Addend parameter.

Comment: Delphi does not declare `InterlockedAdd()` yet (not even in the latest version, Delphi 10 Seattle), but the function exists in the Win32 API nonetheless.  Delphi does declare the `InterlockedExchangeAdd()` function, though, and has for a long long time.

Comment: what is the difference between InterlockedExchangeAdd and InterlockedAdd?  I can't see any difference.

Comment: MSDN has these as cdecl

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But Delphi has them as `stdcall`.

Comment: @DoctorLai: `InterlockedExchangeAdd()` returns "*the initial value of the Addend parameter*", whereas `InterlockedAdd()` returns "*the result of the operation*" instead.  Also, "*The InterlockedAdd function is only available on the Itanium platform. On x86 and x86-64 platforms you can use InterlockedExchangeAdd instead.*"

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why that is so? These are intrinsics rather than exports from a Windows DLL I think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `InterlockedExchangeAdd()` is exported from kernel32.dll.

Comment: But not InterlockedAdd, I think